# 403 Forbidden Without API Key

Tags: google-maps-static-api

So just realized I needed an API key in order to track google maps usage per project. I have been using a URL that I found online to test within my App (I just changed the Longitude, Latitude, and Zoom). So I just received the 403 Forbidden Error and went online to find out why, got an API code added it to my Static Maps URL and I still have the error.

My URL:

```
URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?"
        +Avatar.Vector.Latitude+","+Avatar.Vector.Longitude+
            "&zoom="+Zoom
            +"&scale=2&size=640x640&sensor=true?a.jpg"
            +"&key="+Key;
```

Where Key = my API key.

Why am I still blocked?

Sean

Comment: If you move the key line above the scale line does that fix the problem?

Comment: @theduck: I just tried, still forbidden.

Comment: What about allowed referrers - are those set correctly?

Comment: I am still blocked....